# Number of possible candidates in $n$ tests

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we want to choose $n$ candidates out of a sufficiently large class of people. Then we give $n$ tests to all these people, assuming that in each test, we have a complete order of their scores where any two of them are distinct.

Then, we choose the $n$ candidate as follows.
We choose one test, and select the person with the highest score.
Then we choose another test, and select the person with the highest score among those who have not been chosen in the first test.
We repeat this process for all tests, and finally we choose $n$ candidates out.

The question is, at most how many people MAY be selected because of how we order the tests, if the $n$ tests are fixed but unknown?

---

An example for $n = 2$ is as follows.

Suppose the order of people in the two tests are:

- Test 1: A > B > C > ...
- Test 2: A > C > B > ...

Then, if we choose Test 1 first, the two candidates will be A and C; otherwise, the two candidates will be A and B. Therefore, there are 3 possible candidates, and this is the largest number we can get across all possible results of the two tests.

---

I can only get an lower bound of $2n - 1$, achieved when the first $n-1$ people in every test is the same. I guess this should be also an upper bound, but cannot prove it or give a counterexample.

Comment: I would have thought that if every test produces the same order of candidates then you will end up with the same $n$ people no matter how you arrange the tests, so the lower bound would be $n$.  Similarly if the $n$ tests each produce different candidates in first place then you again end up with the same $n$ people no matter how you arrange the tests, so the same lower bound.  Perhaps I have misunderstood.

Comment: Yes I agree, the lower bound of n is trivial. But I am interested in the maximum number of candidates there can be. I meant that the lower bound for such maximum number is $2n-1$.

Comment: @BoLiu I would remove your use of the word "randomly". You care about all possible (ordering) choices, not just a "random" one.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE Aug 9: Much further generalizations (further update: I retracted the $O(3^k)$ claim. Sorry!)

**Theorem:** For $n = 2^k$ i.e. powers of $2$, there exists a solution with $m_k = (k+2) 2^{k-1}$ candidates.  For these solutions the no. of candidates grow as $m_k \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}kn = O(n \log n)$.

Define a **test** $T=$ ranking of the sufficiently large ground set of people.

Define a **candidate of test** $T =$ a person $X$ who can be chosen because of $T$, i.e. there exists a permutation of the tests s.t. when $T$ comes up in the permutation $X$ is the top (not yet chosen) scorer.  Also, a **candidate** $=$ a person who is a candidate of some test.

**Lemma 1:** For a given test $T$, if person $X$ is a candidate of $T$, then any person $Y$ ahead of $X$ in $T$'s ranking is also a candidate of $T$.

**Proof:** in the permutation that chooses $X$, $Y$ has already been chosen due to some other test $T'$, so a different permutation that would have used $T$ instead of $T'$ would choose $Y$ because of $T$.

**Corollary:** For a given test $T$, it makes sense to define the **last candidate** $Last(T)$ as the candidate of $T$ who ranks lowest in $T$.  I.e. this is the last person who can be chosen because of $T$.  (There can be some candidates, not of $T$, much further down the ranking since each ranking is supposed to be a total order.)

For a given $n$, we are interested in creating a set $S$ of $n$ tests maximizing the total no. of candidates.  In this post, I only consider sets with this property:

Define **Unique-last-candidates set** = a set where $\forall \ T_1, T_2 \in S$ where $T_1 \neq T_2: Last(T_1)$ is not a candidate of $T_2$.  I.e. the last candidates are all different and they don't appear as non-last candidates anywhere.  Note: this property is true for the original example of mathworker21 and my previous generalization.

Define **an $(n, m)$ solution** $=$ a set of $n$ tests with $m$ candidates.

**Proof of theorem:** Given an $(n, m)$ solution, we now construct a $(2n, 2m+n)$ solution.  Construction steps:

1. Duplicate the $n$ tests of the $(n, m)$ solution using entirely different people (letters).  This is a $(2n, 2m)$ solution.

```
AA   ->   AA aa
BC   ->   BC bc

(lower case != upper case)
```

2. For the unique last candidates of the original solution, replace their new counterparts with the originals:

```
AA aa
BC BC <- duplicate but reuse old letters in this row
```

3. Add new unique person to each test:

```
AA aa
BC BC <- duplicate but reuse old letters in this row
DE FG
```

We now prove that the new unique persons are indeed last candidates.  Consider e.g. `D` above, which is a child of the original solution's last candidate `B`.  Consider a permutation that chooses `B` in the original, and repeat it, up to and excluding the test choosing `B`, for both the left side and right side of the duplicate.  At this point, either left or right `B` can be next.  Simply choose the test that chooses the `B` not above `D`, then next choose the test that chooses `D`.  This proves every new person we just added is indeed a last candidate of its respective test, and lemma 1 shows all the old candidates (now non-last candidates) are also still candidates.

I am sorry the proof is not more precise.  I tried to write it precisely but got hopelessly tangled up in notations.

Now count the no. of candidates in the new solution.  Step 1 generates $2m$ candidates, but step 2 takes away $n$ of them, and step 3 adds back $2n$ of them, so the total is $2m+n$ and this is a $(2n, 2m+n)$ solution as claimed.

Using this construction repeatedly, we can generate a series of solutions like this:

```
k=0,n=1,m=1:  A (lone candidate also last candidate)

k=1,n=2,m=3:  AA <- duplicate but reuse old letters in this row
              BC

k=2,n=4,m=8:  AAXX
              BCBC <- duplicate but reuse old letters in this row
              DEFG

k=3,n=8,m=20: AAXX aaxx
              BCBC bcbc
              DEFG DEFG <- duplicate but reuse old letters in this row
              IJKL MNPQ

etc.
```

In this series of solutions, the $k$-th solution has $n_k = 2^k$ and $m_k = 2m_{k-1} + n_{k-1} = 2m_{k-1} + 2^{k-1}$, with $m_0 = 1, m_1 = 3$ as starting points.

Finally we show the recurrence $\implies m_k = (k+2)2^{k-1}$ by induction:

$$
\begin{array}
&m_1 &=& (1+2) 2^0 =3 \text{...base case}\\
m_{k+1} &=& 2 m_k + 2^k\\
&=& 2[(k+2)2^{k-1}] + 2^k\\
&=& (k+2)2^k + 2^k\\
&=& (k+3)2^k\\
&=& ((k+1) + 2) 2^{(k+1)-1} \text{...induction case}
\end{array}
$$

**Further thoughts:** I am not sure the unique-last-candidates criterion is that useful, but the construction does meet the criterion and simplifies the proof, or at least simplifies my thinking.  I also don't know that this is the max, or how to generalize to non powers of $2$.

---

Original post Aug 8: A generalization of
@mathworker21's answer, showing $n=8$ can reach $19$ candidates.

First, after staring a long time, I finally can kinda see a pattern in that answer.  It's a sort of unbalanced binary tree, with unique leaf nodes.

```
(I changed some letters to make it more intuitive for myself.)

1234
----
AAAA
BBCD
CDEF
GH**

* = cannot be reached, therefore irrelevant
```

The main idea is that by choosing which `C` to include, we can include `E` vs `G`, and same for `D, F, H`.

I cannot quite generalize the unbalanced binary tree, but repeating the $n=4$ pattern in the following "imperfect copy" way, leads to $19$ candidates:

```
1234 5678
---- ----
AAAA AAAA
BBCD XXYZ
CDEF YZEF
GHIJ GHKL
MN** PQ**
```

First of all, by previous result, any of `ABCDEFGH XYZ` ($11$ total) can be reached. So all I need to show is that the remaining $8$ letters `IJKLMNPQ` can also be reached.

`M, N, P, Q` are symmetric so reaching `M` suffices for them all, and again the main idea is we can control which `G` to include to decide `M` vs `P`, so: `4(A) 2(B) 3(C) 6(X) 7(Y) 5(G) 1(M)`

`I, J, K, L` are symmetric so reaching `I` suffices for them all: `4(A) 2(B) 1(C) 6(X) 5(Y) 7(E) 3(I)`

Comment: Did you remove the recurrence (since you now solved it)?

Comment: Good point, lemme add it back.  Sorry this went through so many edits as I found out more stuff.  I should have finalized the whole thing before posting once.

Comment: Nice! (And nicely written!) Sorry for the delay (whole family, including me, has covid (but we're all fine)). First of all, just a quick notational note: (big) $O$ refers to upper bounds and $\Omega$ refers to lower bounds. What you showed is that we have an $\Omega(n\log n)$ lower bound, at least when restricted to $n$ being a power of $2$. But, secondly, I don't think we are that restricted to powers of $2$; you can simply ignore some of the tests and still have $\Omega(n \log n)$ candidates (with a slightly worse implicit constant).

Comment: So, where do we go from here? I'll try to improve your construction (at all), but I do suspect $\Theta(n\log n)$ (i.e., $O(n\log n)$ and $\Omega(n \log n)$) is the truth. I'd appreciate hearing of any improvements at all to the lower bound. As for the upper bound, I think it's easy to improve over (literally) $n^2$, but do you see how to prove an upper bound of, say, $n^2/100$? [Btw, I don't know the answer to $n=4$.]

Comment: Doh!  Of course you are right about $O(), \Omega()$ and my result is $\Omega(n \log n)$.  Thanks.  It doesnt happen often that I try to lower-bound something, so I got sloppy.  Also agree re: non-powers-of-$2$ but I was too lazy to think through those and decided to just make the clearer and more restrictive claim.  I did try to improve the upperbound as well, but didnt try too hard and only got e.g. $(n^2 + n)/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Neat question!

The lower bound $2n-1$ is **not** tight, i.e., it is **not** an upper bound.

For $N=4$, consider the following test scores (each column corresponds to a test):

A A A A

B B C D

C D F G

E H B F.

I claim each of the 8 people A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H can be selected as a candidate. Calling the tests $1,2,3,4$ from left to right, we can select each of the people by selecting the tests in the given order:

A,B,C,D: $1,2,3,4$

E : $4,2,3,1$

F : $4,2,1,3$

G : $3,1,2,4$

H : $3,1,4,2$.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out this. I was wondering how you came up with such arrangement -- does the way you come up with this gives hint to the general situation of larger n?

Comment: @BoLiu I was wondering the same thing. I just played around with stuff until I found this example. I'm not sure if/how it generalizes.

Comment: hi mathworker21, long time no see!  love your answer!!  (i was trying so hard to find some invariant to prove the $2n-1$ conjecture...  no wonder i couldnt!)

Comment: @antkam hey!!!! I actually thought of you when I saw this question. Hope you've been well. I saw a couple weeks ago that you hadn't been on for a long time. In any event, I'm curious what the asymptotic truth is to this question (or even the exact truth) -- is it $O(n)$, or $\Omega(n^2)$, or something else?

Comment: I would be shocked if it's $O(n^2)$.  In fact, if I were to bet ... maybe $O(n \log n)$?  I am not sure.  Re: my absence, yeah I miss MSE, but my new job (well, been 3+ years now) is soooo busy that I usually don't have time nor energy left to read or think about MSE.  :(

Comment: I actually came back to MSE recently because I wanted to ask [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740703/minimum-swaps-to-put-an-array-into-desired-order-where-some-elements-are-identi).  I even offered a bounty (my first!) but nobody could help.

Comment: wow, turns out I was very wrong about $n \log n$ and your $n^2$ intuition is much closer!

Comment: @antkam Wow!! No, I had the same intuition of $n\log n$ as you and thought $n^2$ was ridiculous. I would have never guessed an $n^{1.58}$ lower bound. Wow! I'll read carefully soon. I'll also take a look at your question!

Comment: I have the recurrence, but I have lost the skill to solve it and therefore I'm not sure about the growth.  Maybe I'm wrong? :(

Comment: UGH i posted too soon.  Should have waited for my python script which shows $m$ seems to grow as $O(n \log n)$.  I wish I could solve my recurrence!  If you could help that would be much appreciated.